# Codeigniter Auth Library - username public profiles for specific group, disabled for other groups

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication, profiles

currently working on an application that has 3 distinct user groups. Admins, Entrants and General Users. Admins will have a backend and can do anything, that's ok not a problem.

Entrants must have a username and this will be used as their public profile: domain.com/username ... or a variation of. They also have a private profile in which they can edit.

I do not want general users to have public profiles but they will have a private profile in which they can edit their name, details, etc.

Can anyone recommend one of the many Auth libraries that can best suit this purpose or if i should develop an app like this in Codeigniter at all!!

```
Overview:

Admins (Max 2 - 3 users) - Access Everything
Entrants - Public Profile(username) / Private Profile
General Users - Private Profile Only
```

Many thanks and any help/advice is much appreciated. Apologies if it's been asked already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I always have used Ion_Auth.  It does contain distinct user groups and the ability to provide access control depending on the group..

https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

I have also put together an **[example of its usage here](https://github.com/jondavidjohn/auth_example)**, based on [**this blog post**](http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/01/scalable-login-system-for-codeigniter-ion_auth).

Comment: where's your extended controllers, specifically the MY_controller in your example??? I'm reading your blog post but can't find it, is it conveniently named something else?

Comment: I don't go all the way through creating new base controllers in my github example, just simple authentication logic.